# Unable to access http sites

Tags: networking, update-manager

Until recently I could access http sites, then about two weeks ago http sites stopped working and now I can only use https.  I would be grateful for help in getting http working again.

I have tried following the same http link from ubuntu 20.04 and also from my Android phone.  The link I've tested most is `http://google.co.uk/`, and I know I'm using the same link both times because I stored it in my Google Keep, and I click it from there.  I also made sure I'm using the same WiFi network each time.  The link works from Android, but not from either of my Ubuntu 20.04 boxes.  I know that for Google I can easily just use an https link instead, but here I'm just using it as a test for http.

When I try to access `http://google.co.uk/` using `curl`, I get the following, with a long delay before the `Recv failure` is shown:

```
$ curl --verbose http://google.co.uk/
*   Trying 172.217.16.227:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to google.co.uk (172.217.16.227) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: google.co.uk
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

This is particularly a problem because Ubuntu updates seem to be served over http, and I am also unable to update Ubuntu.  I just get a status saying `[Waiting for headers]` and then eventually `Connection failed`.

Comment: very few web adresses are unsecured http now most is blocked by your web browser,most sites have changed to https now.

Comment: @trondhansen - I know that https is now commonplace.  But it's not universal, and in particular, Ubuntu is serving updates via http.

Comment: i am not sure this problem of yours is ubuntu related,i am not aware anybody else reporting this problem in updating ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @Chris Gill If you are happy with the answer accept it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my fixed-line broadband ISP was blocking access to http sites.  I tried connecting using a mobile hotspot and was able to connect to http sites and to update Ubuntu.  I've now been in touch with my ISP who kind of accidentally fixed the problem during our conversation by turning something off and on again.  Oh well, it's fixed (for) now, at least.

Answer (score 1):

If you need HTTP or HTTPS is a feature of the web site you are trying to access.

This is not something you can control other then using the right command.

Many web sites now a days are HTTPS and you will often get an error message when trying to access a site with HTTP that you should be using HTTPS.

HTTPS is already the default for Google sites.

Comment: The Google web site was just an example.  And some resources (such as Ubuntu security updates) are only available using HTTP; they don't have an HTTPS option.  That's why I need to get this working again.